# facebook problem : application goes to original domain

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook application with PHP and facing two main problems..

1. When I click allow on the permission, the app takes me to my own domain (where application is stored) instead of loading it in an iFrame.
2. Sometimes when I click "Don't allow", it still lets me in and shows a PHP error, while sometimes (most of the times), it doesn't let me in.

What could be the problem? Any way I can programatically redirect to the permissions page? Thank you..

```
if(empty ($this->session))
    {
        try
        {
            $login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
            header("Location: ".$login_url);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            header("Location: http://www.facebook.com");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            $this->uid = $this->facebook->getUser();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            header("Location: http://www.facebook.com");
        }
    }
```

note the redirects I made were to try to solve the problem. But no exception is thrown.

Comment: provide the code you are using, i am 90% sure about your problem, but let me see the code (the login and request permission part) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this simple script to apply redirect if the page is not inside iFrame...

```
if(parent == window)
                {
                    window.location = "http://apps.facebook.com/appname/";
                }
```

This might not be a legal solution, but solved the situation for me. Anybody if knows the legal way, please post. Thanks.

Comment: but your application is set to FBML, not iframe ?

Comment: look closer, it is set to iframe. So I need it to go with iframe only. If it is not in iframe, then it is clearly running on my own site. That's the catch...

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get the login url you can pass different params based on what you need. in your case, to go back to facebook page url you can use the `next` param.

This is your code modified:

```
$login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'canvas'    => 1,
                'fbconnect' => 0,
                'next' => YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL
            ) 
        );
if(empty ($this->session))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
else
{
    try
    {
        $this->uid = $this->facebook->getUser();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it solves your problem :)

Comment: For some reason, it still is sending me to my domain. I found a rather hacking type of solution to it. See my answer.

Comment: Are you sure you did everything correctly? I had the same issue and adding the `next` parameter solved the problem. One more thing, take a look at the query string when you see the permissions dialog. Do you have a `next` parameter having the value set to your application canvas page url ?